# Move cursor to the middle of the screen in emacs

Tags: vim, emacs, text-cursor

In vim you have the keys which move the cursor and not the page

H -- move to top of screen

L -- move to bottom of screen

M -- move to middle of screen

Is there something similar in emacs??

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do this with `move-to-window-line-top-bottom` (bound to
`M-r`).  See `(info "(emacs) Moving point")` for more information.

Answer (score 1):

…and the mandatory comment: you can do the same if you use [evil-mode](http://wikemacs.org/index.php/Evil), the vim layer.

Install (with [melpa](http://wikemacs.org/wiki/MELPA)):

```
package-install evil RET
```

use:

```
M-x evil-mode
```